# Propose new meeting time in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there anyway to propose a new meeting time by using MS Graph API, i searched all the api in the document and can not find any suitable api for that function.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, that isn't there in the API today. This would be a great feature though. I recommend suggesting it on [UserVoice](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: yeah, the EWS even dont expose this API. I'm trying to recreate this Propose by adding custome step. thanks jason